# No results are returned in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, return

I am trying to take the average every fifth and every sixth row of var A in a dataframe, and put the result in a new column as var B. But it `NaN` shows. It may be resulted by I did not return values correctly?

Here is the sample data:

```
PID    A     
1      0
1      3
1      2
1      6
1      0
1      2
2      3
2      3
2      1
2      4
2      0
2      4
```

Expected results:

```
PID    A      B  
1      0      1
1      3      1
1      2      1
1      6      1
1      0      1
1      2      1
2      3      2
2      3      2
2      1      2
2      4      2
2      0      2
2      4      2
```

My codes:

```
lst1 = df.iloc[5::6, :] 
lst2 = df.iloc[4::6, :]  

df['B'] = (lst1['A'] + lst2['A'])/2
print(df['B'])
```

The script can be run without error, but the var B is empty and show `NaN`.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem data not aligned, because different indexes, so get `NaN`s.

```
print(lst1)
    PID  A
5     1  2
11    2  4

print(lst2)
    PID  A
4     1  0
10    2  0

print (lst1['A'] + lst2['A'])
4    NaN
5    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Solution is use `values` for add `Series` to `numpy array`:

```
print (lst1['A'] + (lst2['A'].values))
5     2
11    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Or you can sum 2 numpy arrays:

```
print (lst1['A'].values + (lst2['A'].values))
[2 4]
```

It seems you need:

```
df['B'] = (lst1['A'] + lst2['A'].values).div(2)
df['B'] = df['B'].bfill()
print(df)
    PID  A    B
0     1  0  1.0
1     1  3  1.0
2     1  2  1.0
3     1  6  1.0
4     1  0  1.0
5     1  2  1.0
6     2  3  2.0
7     2  3  2.0
8     2  1  2.0
9     2  4  2.0
10    2  0  2.0
11    2  4  2.0
```

But if need `mean` of `5.` and `6.` value per group by `PID` use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['B']  = df.groupby('PID').transform(lambda x: x.iloc[[4, 5]].mean())
print(df)
    PID  A    B
0     1  0  1.0
1     1  3  1.0
2     1  2  1.0
3     1  6  1.0
4     1  0  1.0
5     1  2  1.0
6     2  3  2.0
7     2  3  2.0
8     2  1  2.0
9     2  4  2.0
10    2  0  2.0
11    2  4  2.0
```

Comment: Thx! If the indexes are the problem, I try to use `reset_index(drop=True)` to drop the index and then take the average, but `NaN` is still the problem. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: There is problem different indexes and pandas want same in both df. So need `lst1 = lst1.reset_index(drop=True)` and `lst1 = lst1.reset_index(drop=True)` - then is possible add and divide by 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Straightforward way taking the mean of the 5th and 6th positions within each group defined by `'PID'`.

```
df.assign(B=df.groupby('PID').transform(lambda x: x.values[[4, 5]].mean()))

    PID  A    B
0     1  0  1.0
1     1  3  1.0
2     1  2  1.0
3     1  6  1.0
4     1  0  1.0
5     1  2  1.0
6     2  3  2.0
7     2  3  2.0
8     2  1  2.0
9     2  4  2.0
10    2  0  2.0
11    2  4  2.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Fun way using `join` assuming there are actually exactly 6 rows for each `'PID'`.

```
df.join(df.set_index('PID').A.pipe(lambda d: (d.iloc[4::6] + d.iloc[5::6]) / 2).rename('B'), on='PID')

    PID  A    B
0     1  0  1.0
1     1  3  1.0
2     1  2  1.0
3     1  6  1.0
4     1  0  1.0
5     1  2  1.0
6     2  3  2.0
7     2  3  2.0
8     2  1  2.0
9     2  4  2.0
10    2  0  2.0
11    2  4  2.0
```